# Will 5 year residency permits be available in Turkey after the new 2014 visa laws take effect?

Tags: resident-permit, turkey

I know that Turkey is still issuing 5 year residence permits (ikamet tezkeresi) as of March, 2014. However the whole visa system is changing this April. All the mentions of ikamets in documents I have been able to find about the new rules are about 1 year permits. Will 3 and 5 year permits continue to be an option under the new rules? If so to citizens of what countries will they be issued and what conditions must be met?

Comment: You provide little background. It would seem to be unclear as to who these visa procedures apply to. The entire world or just some nationalities. Also what would be useful is to provide hyperlinks that corroborate or support any statement you make (if possible) since that would help immensely!

Comment: I could ramble on about the mixed signals and how confusing this is and throw links at the wall but I don't think any of it would make this a better question. It is going to take more than a Google search the answer this, if you don't have any knowledge about the situation then you probably aren't the one the answer.

Comment: No crystal balls here. Turkey is not known for its opacity. Nevertheless, typing from the future as I am....

Answer (score 1):

No. Now the only permits available now are [1 year renewable permits and 8 year long term permits](https://www.expatguideturkey.com/residence-permits/).

Comment: 2 year permits are available in most provinces, but only on renewal.

Comment: Good to know. Would you mind providing a link?